# Collectionview with different cell sizes creating issues on reloadItemAtIndex call

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having a UICollectionView with flow layout and according to my need it's cells are varing in size so i have implemented sizeForItemAtIndexPath delegate method as...

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CGSize estimatedSize;
estimatedSize.width = collectionView.frame.size.width - 2* MARGIN_8;
CGSize questionSize=[self sizeOfText:myData[indexPath.row] constraintWidth:estimatedSize.width constraintsHeight:MAXFLOAT andFont:CELL_FONT];
estimatedSize.height = ceil(questionSize.height>MINIMUM_HEIGHT_OF_OPTION_TEXT?questionSize.height:MINIMUM_HEIGHT_OF_OPTION_TEXT);return estimatedSize;}
```

Now, the problem is when a call reloaItemAtItem method for updating the selected cell, as ....

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
userSelection = (int)indexPath.row;
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];}
```

it says

`UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x147a0190> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}`

and the screen gets stop responding. But when giving same sizes for all the cells this issue doesn't come and it works fine. Can anybody tell what's the problem is??

Answer (score 0):

To make collection view with cells of different sizes you need to implement custom flow layout of your as per below link:

https://bradbambara.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/getting-started-with-custom-uicollectionview-layouts/

I had same requirement to show two cell in one section when app is in landscape mode and show one cell in each section if it's in portrait mode, I have shared the demo for it on below link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzVs5BNlAI6qdjcwcnVHN1Z5NW8/view

I hope this will help you.

Comment: we can make cells of different sizes without customizing flow layout as i m doing this and it is running fine.... but the issue occuring with reloadItemAtIndex method call. I m not getting why this running fine on reloadData but not on reloadItemAtIndex call.

Comment: hey this issues get resolved the problem was in my sizeOfText:(NSString *) constraintWidth:(float) constraintsHeight(float) andFont:(float) method. Anyways thxs @harish

Comment: Okay that's great, glad to hear that.